# pendrive distro

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, usb-drive

Which distro should I install on my 8GB pendrive? I need it to have powerfull repos (everything, music editing is crushial) and should be lightweighting not losing on functionality. Any propositions? PS: I'm now on windows.

EDIT: I'd like to use XFCE and light-weighting should be priority. I mean I'd like to choose all packages from scratch.

Comment: i would suggest `fedora 16` or `ubuntu 11.10` for all its functionalities it is based. it has yum repo/apt-get and has all functionalities you needed

Comment: I don't want ubuntu cause I have to choose the space I want to use between boots. This is really annoying cause I want to have all data on one / partition. I'll check fedora in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend Gentoo, but it's not for the faint of heart. Really it would depend on your experience level with Linux.

With it you can customize for performance the packages you install without bloating getting a bloated system.

Also I'd recommend looking into fluxbox or openbox for a minimalistic window manager.

Comment: Is there any tutorial how could I install it on pendrive? I'm just to tired to do it by my self after trying whole day installing arch.

Comment: +1 for gentoo. I don't know of any premade USB-distro that is made to run on a stick. But you should be able to install every distro onto a USB-Stick. And gentoo is extremely lightweight if you use the "minimal" USE-flag for some packages. An alternative might be Archlinux if you don't want to dive too deep into your system.

Comment: @oneat substitute everything with the pendrives device path (or even better UUID). I am booting my server from a pendrive, would be no problem to put the rest of the system on it too. I would reccomend using genkernel if you want to switch your host-PC though.

Comment: @oneat Yes, http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/liveusb.xml I've used these instructions to recover an installation also

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is fedora. You can easily generate custom live iso using kickstart files.

I always keep fedora with security and some general tools on pendrive.
It is also useful when recovering existing installation via chroot.